# My donut has icing rings inside the donut

Tags: modifiers

[image]I have created the same exact donut problem 12 times, I have each one numbered.  I follow exactly.  When I shiftd esc, I have icing.  When you go into the edit mode, I get rings around the donut, light and dark.  I am so new, I have read everything on icing problems but I do not see anyone else's donut looking as sad as mine.  If I move the vertices, they go right into the donut.  I have messed with other options and at first it was amusing, then I became despondent.  I seriously only know what the Guru has taught through #3.  This is what my donut and icing look like.

Comment: It looks like your icing has clipped into the donut. The dark part are the donut faces. Try lifting the top verts a little higher. (Press "2" for edge mode then "alt+click" for loop select and "g" ,"z" to grab the selection in Z axis)

Comment: Thank you!  I just felt that was the problem but had no idea how to accomplish all that.  I will try that right now, oh thank you!

Comment: Filip, thank you.  It worked.  Now onto my next hard stop problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the magnet icon at the top and turn it on. Then click on the arrow next to it and select "Face." Then check "Project Individual Elements."